# CSS: how to make a DIV with display: table-celll extend 100% in width

Tags: css

I use Bootstrap 3. I have the following HTML (jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mddc/6ntwb431/5/)

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="background-color: yellow">
        <div class="alert">This is alert!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.alert {
    height: 40px;
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: red;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I am hoping the .alert DIV extend 100% in width within its containing DIV, but cannot figure it out how after many tests.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap the "table-cell" inside a table. So in this case you add the following to the row class

```
.row{
    display:table;
    width:100%;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should add `table-row` diplsay property to your `.row` class:

```
.row {
    display: table-row;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6ntwb431/7/